# How to print two array lists in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like `var myArr = [0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6];`

I want to separate all positive No's and negative No's in array format like

`positiveArr = [0,2,4,6]` and `negativeArr = [-1,-3,-5]`.

Then like to print both arrays in object format.

Final expected result something like an object:

```
{Positive: [0,2,4,6], Negative: [-1,-3,-5]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: which languages? what did you do so far?

Comment: Write into console -> `Computer I command: Split myArr = [0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6]; into Positive numbers and Negative numbers. Disobedience will be punished by formating the hard drive.` And if it does not work, format all disks, otherwise the computer will be laughing at you.

Comment: Does the order matter? Is it okay to get, say, `[-5, -3, -1]` for the `Negative` array?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const myArr = [0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6];

const result = myArr.reduce((all, item) => {

    const key = item >= 0 ? 'Positive' : 'Negative';

    all[key].push(item);

    return all;

}, {Positive: [], Negative: []});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: very smart solution, +1. The logic of the initial value very ingenious

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your array definition, you are using JavaScript - don't forget to add the tag `javascript`.

You need the following output:

```
var obj = {positive: new Array(), negative: new Array()};
```

Iterate *once* through all the elements and add them to the correct array:

```js
var myArr = [0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6];
var obj = {positive: new Array(), negative: new Array()};
myArr.forEach(i => { 
    if (i>=0) { obj.positive.push(i) } else { obj.negative.push(i); }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

The result `obj` will have the following arrays:

```
negative : (3) [-1, -3, -5]
positive : (4) [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Printed out with [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will result in:

```
{"positive":[0,2,4,6],"negative":[-1,-3,-5]}
```

Comment: Hi Denis. Thank you. Your output shows both array list separately. I would like to print exactly  { Positive: [0, 2, 4, 6], Negative: [-1, -3, -5] } . I mean both array lists separated by comma inside curly braces.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use ob the `obj` the following: [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in JavaScript, you can do so

```js
let myArr = [0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6];
let obj = {Positive: myArr.filter(e => e < 0), Negative: myArr.filter(e => e >= 0)};
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I don't recommend to iterate through array *twice*.

Comment: @Nikolas Why? filter function makes new array, so I don't see any problem

Comment: Yes, it returns an array. But you call this function twice and it iterates the entire array.

Comment: So, you mean perfomance, I absolutely agree, but in such cases it doesn't matter, both solutions are good but my shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit, and is totally find

```
const numbers = [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6];
const positives = numbers.filter(number => number >= 0);
const negatives = numbers.filter(number => number < 0)
const results = {positives: positives, negatives: negatives}

console.log(results); // {positives: [0, 2, 4 ,6], negatives: [-1, -3, -5]}
```

I attached an executable example

```js
const numbers = [0, -1 , 2, -3, 4, -5, 6];
const positives = numbers.filter(number => number >= 0);
const negatives = numbers.filter(number => number < 0);
const results = {positives: positives, negatives: negatives};

console.log(results);
```

Comment: It does not give the output as expected. It gives [object Object] instead of { positive: [0,2,4,6], negative: [-1,-3,-5] } where is the wrong? I checked in my system. Thanks

Comment: @user615274: I don't recommend to iterate through array *twice*.

Comment: Hi Bhagabat, I updated the answer with an runnable snippet

Comment: I agree Nikolas, in honor of the truth at the time I did not think of a more compact solution like the one presented by Leonid Pyrlia. On the other hand I think sometimes new users appreciate a solution that is a bit easier to understand

Comment: I am learning JavaScript. I am new to this community. I am happy for the quick response for my query. I really thankful to all and this community. I need your support to learn this language. Any suggestion for me is most welcome. How to learn and master this quickly? Once again thanks a lot everyone.